# Increased Stability of Vortex Rings by Pushing it

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stability, vortex

I've noticed in playing around with smoke rings that they are substantially more stable in their axial motion if pushed from behind by a hand, as can be seen in various Youtube videos. I was wondering how to derive this effect from say the Navier-Stokes equations using appropriate boundary conditions. References would be appreciated.

Link to phenomenon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yqEf6Bo50E (Apologies for the vape connection).

Comment: Please add a link to a video that shows what you mean.

Comment: Are you sure the video is showing an increase in stability? All I can see for sure is an increase in speed.